# View database in Derby inside java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I use `Derby` as my java game desktop database. My database save inside the project folder. Now I am having troubled in viewing my tables. Is there a way to view database inside the `eclipse` project folder?

Comment: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-EclipseDbWebapps/2006-04-10/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding the `Derby-plugins` to your ide, you can find it [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/start_toc.html).

Also a similar one here [How to browse a derby memory database with Eclipse Datasource Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796697/how-to-browse-a-derby-memory-database-with-eclipse-datasource-explorer).

But , i personally find this [**tutorial**](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html) useful . Also have a look at [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial/3.8/Database_Development_Perspective).

Comment: I used eclipse data source explorer but it save outside my project folder. When I published my game, it has a possibility to not be included in my executable jar?

Comment: yes it might , it is not portable with your project . Because it is the plugin for the eclipse

Comment: You need to install it on the eclipse ide wherever you use or port your own ide

Answer (score 0):

You can use some third party software to view the tables. SquirrelSQL for example is tool which enables to view the database content.